# 18.04 keeps going into airplane mode and I need to reboot the computer

Tags: wireless, 18.04, airplane-mode

I find that if I leave my laptop unattended for a few hours, it sometimes goes into airplane mode. I can't switch the wifi back on using the settings menu and when I mouseover on the upper right hand side of the screen (where the power left, volume etc and other icons are), it says that the wifi is "hardware disabled." I have to turn the laptop off and then back on to resume wifi. I'm using a HP Pavillion laptop btw

Comment: Same for me using asus fx553vd and kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

So I had this issue and figured the problem was with the hardware.

I ordered an inexpensive, and small (best value) wireless adapter 802.11ac

Ubuntu 18 (19 and 20) didn't come with support out of the box for it and I tried several versions of drivers that claimed to support it. I followed a GitHub fork chain until I found one that worked. Here's my saved repo for it. Follow the instructions verbatim for the make file (while you still have an internet connection)

https://github.com/Tclack88/rtl8822bu

EDIT: Instructions held therein:

```
git clone https://github.com/Tclack88/rtl8822bu.git
cd rtl8822bu
```

Now with the device plugged in, compile and install firmware files:

```
make
sudo make install
```

to allow for rebuilds/installs when/if your kernel updates, use DKMS:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

then install the module with dkms in the source directory:

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install -m 88x2bu -v 1.1
```

If this doesn't work for you and you decide to move onto different instructions but  want to declutter the junk, uninstall as follows:

```
sudo dkms remove -m 88x2bu -v 1.1 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/88x2bu-1.1
```

Comment: I know what you're saying generally, but here, the instructions are specific to the linked content of the GitHub repo. Regardless, edit has been made.